# PHP Set $_SESSION variable value according to (Button/Link) click

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have the following Code :

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a href="index.php?page=quiz" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="index.php?page=quiz" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is to send the category number to the page `index.php?page=quiz`
via `$_POST` or anything else
without sending it via `$_REQUEST` like this `index.php?page=quiz&cat=1`
**OR** assigning the category number value to a `$_SESSION` variable according to current clicked link
to get the value at destination page `index.php?page=quiz`.

**I have already tried this solution:**

Via `javascript` by sending the variable value to the page

```
var num=1; /*or put the current clicked category number */
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?page=quiz',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            category_no: num,
        }
    })
```

There seems to be a problem with the sending process and the value of `page=quiz`
is not send to the destination and we are still on the current page where `page=home`.

**Do you have any helpful ideas?**

**NOTE: My problem is not getting the category id from current clicked (button/link) to `javascript`, but sending it to destination page with any of the ways mentioned above.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explaining Solution:**
The problem was there is no `exit()` and `json_encode()` as results into my function which cannot be applied inside page `index.php` code which mean that
the whole function must be moved to another file 
**the problem solved like following:**
**`my page:`**

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a  href="" data-no="1" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a  href="" data-no="2" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**`JavaScript:`**

```
$('.cat').on('click', function (e) {
    // Prevent default action of link click
    e.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).data('no');
    var curr='set_var.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: curr,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            category: cat

        }
    }).done(function(res) {
            if (res.valid) {
            document.location.href = 'index.php?page=quiz';
        }
        });
});
```

**`set_var.php :`**

```
<?php 
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['category'])){  
        $_SESSION['cat']=$_POST['category'];
        $result['valid'] = TRUE;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit();
 ?>
```

**Thanks for all your answers**

Answer (score 0):

Add the category id as a data attribute like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a data-category-id="1" href="index.php?page=quiz" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a  data-category-id="2" href="index.php?page=quiz" class="cat" >
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <p>(explain here)</p>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then handle the click event like this to make your ajax call (dynamically get the clicked category link's url and it's id):

```
// When page loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Handle category click event
    $('a.cat').click(function(e)
    {
        // Prevent default action of link click
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the url
        var categoryUrl = $(this).prop('href');

        // Get the category id
        var categoryId = $(this).data('category-id');

        // Make ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: categoryUrl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                category_no: categoryId
            }
        })
        .done(function() {
            location.href = categoryUrl;
        });
    })
});
```

This way, when you click the link (default action of going to the url doesn't run). Instead; an ajax POST request is made to clicked url (in your case always `index.php?page=quiz`) first and when the request completes, then you are redirected to that page.

Comment: i've already tried this solution and there are multiple sulotion to send category id to javascript function , my problem is not with getting category id from current button to java script , my problem is with sending it to destination page

Comment: What do you mean by destination page? when a link is clicked, where are you trying to make the ajax post request to?

Comment: Current page is : index.php?page=home , distenation page is :index.php?page=quiz

Comment: It is possible the page is loading before the ajax request had a chance to execute or run to completion. I will update my answer, see above.

Comment: i mentioned above that i can send it like this 
index.php?page=quiz&cat=1
but i dont need to show the cat id for security purpose
i need anoher way to send it , 
Ok i will see it now

Comment: Just my 2 cent; you should implement the security at server level instead of trying to hide it from user by avoiding sending the category id in the url. Users will figure it out as long as the data is there on the page.

Comment: this var is handled with try catch at the server side and with specific limited values it must be received right there,
No the users can't now what i will do with this number because it is just a number ,i can put it like this "data-no=1"
and send it to destination and handle it , i just dont want to tell them that there are category number and send by the url
i have also tried   .done(function() {   }); property with no any advantage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158169/discussion-between-elie-ma-and-latheesan).

Answer (score 0):

If num is your clicked category, I think it should work like:

```
var num=1;
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?page=quiz',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        num,
    }
});
```

And in your 'index.php':

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['catID'] = $_POST['num'];
```

If this doesnt' work, it would be helpful to see your index.php.

Edit: Lets try it with another side .. just for testing.

Create a new php called getCatID.php and change AJAX to:

```
var num=1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getCatID.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            num,
        }
    });
   window.location = "index.php?page=quiz"
```

In the getCatID.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['catID'] = $_POST['num'];
?>
```

And in your index.php try to

```
echo $_SESSION['catID'];
```

PS: You need to trigger the Ajax Call in a way

Comment: ok, I think I missunderstood ur question.Do u want a redirect to the quiz page and show the questions with the clicked category?

Comment: of course i need session wait another comment to describe index page

Comment: my index page is page showing php page according to that variable in the $_REQUEST var in the url that called 'page'
i have tried your solution but may be ajax  cannot be loaded before,
and the page still with value = home,
yes  i need to redirect to quiz page but only by index.php?page=quiz and only by index.php
not by making another page like quiz.php or something